# Is there a tool to get the lines in one file that are not in another?

Tags: command-line

Is there any tool that can get lines which file A contains, but file B doesn't? I could make a little simple script with, e.g, perl, but if something like that already exists, I'll save my time from now on.

Comment: see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812756/print-lines-from-one-file-that-are-not-contained-in-another-file"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Yes. The standard `grep` tool for searching files for text strings can be used to subtract all the lines in one file from another.

```
grep -F -x -v -f fileB fileA
```

This works by using each line in fileB as a pattern (`-f fileB`) and treating it as a plain string to match (not a regular regex) (`-F`). You force the match to happen on the whole line (`-x`) and print out only the lines that don't match (`-v`).  Therefore you are printing out the lines in fileA that don't contain the same data as any line in fileB.

The downside of this solution is that it doesn't take line order into account and if your input has duplicate lines in different places you might not get what you expect. The solution to that is to use a real comparison tool such as `diff`. You could do this by creating a diff file with the context value at 100% of the lines in the file, then parsing it for just the lines that would be removed if converting file A to file B. <sub>(Note this command also removes the diff formatting after it gets the right lines.)</sub>

```
diff -U $(wc -l < fileA) fileA fileB | sed -n 's/^-//p' > fileC
```

Comment: @inderpreet99 The lower case `-u` argument does actually take a parameter of a number as long as it is not followed by a space. The advantage of the way I had it before is that it will work with or without a value, so you could use something in that sub command routine that returned not output. Upper case '-U' on the other hand requires an argument.

Comment: be careful, grep -f is O(N^2) I believe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780203/deleting-lines-from-one-file-which-are-in-another-file

Comment: the `diff` pipeline works a treat thanks.

Comment: To account for the sort problem, you could use [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) in the command to process each file before the `grep` as needed.  Example: `grep -F -x -v -f <(sort fileB) <(sort fileA)`

Comment: @TonyCesaro That would work if your data set is not order specific  and duplicates don't need to be taken into account. The advantage of using `diff` is that position in the file gets taken into account.

Comment: The options can be collapsed together to get a shorter version: `grep -Fxvf fileB fileA`.

Answer (score 64):

The answer depends a great deal on the type and format of the files you are comparing.

If the files you are comparing are sorted text files, then the GNU tool written by Richard Stallman and Davide McKenzie called [`comm`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/comm-invocation.html) may perform the filtering you are after. It is part
of the coreutils.

#### Example

Say you have the following 2 files:

```
$ cat a
1
2
3
4
5

$ cat b
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Lines in file `b` that are not in file `a`:

```
$ comm <(sort a) <(sort b) -3
    6
```

Comment: so sort them ? comm <(sort a) <(sort b) -1 -2

Comment: This is some weird syntax. `<()`? It works and I get it, but is there a name for this weirdness?

Comment: @mlissner `comm` can also read stdin (see man page). `<()`is your redirection.

Comment: @mlissner `<()` is also known as [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Comment: `comm` was originally written circa 1973 by someone at Bell Labs, not rms. You're referring to the GNU implementation which came a lot later. There have been a lot of different implementations of the Unix utilities across the years.

Comment: `comm` doesn't seem to be fitted for use in scripts. E.g. when you show more than one column. To be frank, the first impression, it's weird.

Answer (score 42):

from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366533/remove-lines-from-file-which-appear-in-another-file)...

> comm -23 file1 file2

-23 suppresses the lines in file2 (-2) and the lines that appear in both (-3), leaving only the unique lines from file1. The files have to be sorted (they are in your example) but if not, pipe them through sort first.

See the man page [here](https://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)

```
-1 suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
-2 suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
-3 suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, for some reason ...

Comment: @Jan are your files sorted? How did you sort them?

Comment: @roaima I have additional explanation not supplied by the other answer. Also, I'm adding `-2`, and they are only using `-3`, so not exactly the same.

Comment: @roaima thanks for pointing out that I can improve my answer by standing out from other similar answers!

Comment: This is the best answer because `comm` is purpose-built to do what OP wanted to do. And by "best answer" I mean "will suit for most people", not "will suit for every single use case including absurdly large unsorted files". :D

Answer (score 9):

The grep and comm (with sort) methods take a *long* time on large files. SiegeX and ghostdog74 shared two great [awk methods for extracting lines unique to one of two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4717250/extracting-unique-values-between-2-sets-files) over on Stack Overflow:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++}FNR!=NR && !a[$0]{print}' file1 file2

$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0]++;next}(!($0 in a))' file1 file2
```

Comment: If you're doing this with huge files, then the memory constraints of loading a huge file into an associative array are going to be prohibitive.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, that would be a lot worse with `grep -Fvxf` approach though, where the performance would be unacceptable long before memory exhaustion.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, indeed; for really large files one really ought to use `sort`+`comm`, where better `sort` implementations' ability to generate temporary files and merge-sort them together means that memory constraints are moot. (Of course, keeping content pre-sorted to the extent possible is in this context a Very Good Idea)

Answer (score 5):

If the files are big and you don't have a custom order to your entries, grep takes much too long. A quick alternative would be

```
sort file1 > 1 
sort file2 > 2 
diff 1 2 | grep "\>" | sed -e 's/> //'
```

[file2-file1 results to screen, pipe to file etc.]

Changing `>` to `<` would get the opposite subtraction. `rm 1 2`

Answer (score 3):

`combine` from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) package is very intuitive:

```
combine fileA not fileB
```

The files do not need to be sorted and the order is preserved.

There are also `xor`, `or` and `and` operators.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider vimdiff, it highlights the differences between files in a vim editor

Comment: But is there an easy way to automatically do the subtraction in Vimdiff?

Answer (score 0):

```
    awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next}!($1 in a){print }' fileA fileB

  

     cat fileA
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    
  file B
        8
        9
        10
        11
        12
        13
        14
        15
        16
        17
        18
        19
    
    output
    
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19


    It will print contents of fileB which is not in fileA
```

Comment: Please let me know the reason for down vote

Comment: You want `$0`, not `$1`. Also this is essentially the same as [Miles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/92813).