# awk/grep to match word in two files

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files:

`file1`:

```
905894
1197693
3703749
```

`file2`:

```
905894   Test1
1197693   Test2
3703749  Test3
```

I want to get the values in the second column if elements in file 1 column 1 matches any of the words in file 2 column 1.

I know awk can do it, but stuck in reading file 1 and using a loop.

Comment: You can look at this for reference - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another

Comment: What you need here is either `join -o 2.2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)` or `awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} ($1 in a) {print $2}' file1 file2`

Answer (score 2):

Using `grep`:

```
$ grep -wFf file1 file2 
905894   Test1
1197693   Test2
3703749  Test3
```

- `-f` indicates that we are taking patterns (one per line) to be matched from `file1`
- `-F` will take the patterns from `file1` as fixed strings meaning no further operations with be done on them prior to matching
- `-w` indicates we are matching lines that contains the patterns as whole words. Note that only `[A-Za-z0-9_]` are considered as word constituent characters, any other character will be considered as word delimiter. This will ensure that only whole columns are matched, not anything like `905894abcd` in the columns.

Check `man grep` to get more idea on this.

Comment: Perhaps adding `--word-regexp` would be even better?

Comment: @dhag: would be better in this case..added

Answer (score 0):

I'd use perl myself.

- read in file 1, extract a list of numbers.
- iterate file 2, extracting number and word
- check if 'number' in file2 was present in file1, and if so print the word.

Something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %in_file1;

open( my $file1, "<", "file1.txt" ) or die $!;

while (<$file1>) {
    my ($number) = m/(\d+)/;
    $in_file1{$number}++;
}
close($file1);

open( my $file2, "<", "file2.txt" ) or die $!;

while (<$file2>) {
    my ( $number, $word ) = split;
    if ( $in_file1{$number} ) { print $word, "\n"; }
}

close($file2);
```