# linux + delete words from file that appear in another file

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have two files: in linux redhat version 6

**list1.txt**         - this files contain 34732 words

**list2.txt**         - this files contain 272 words

I want to remove all words from list1.txt that spears from list2.txt

what the best approach to do that ( both files include only one field )

```
more list1.txt

dweferf
fr
grgr
gefyh
fergtrg
ggtgg
fergth
gtg
.
.
.

more list2.txt

dweferf
fr
frgrgggb
rggtgtrgrt
fergtrg
rfergrtg
fwed4

.
.
.
```

Comment: "spears"? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I mean that all words/string in list1.txt that match the list in list2.txt should be deleted from list1.txt  , so list1.txt will not include the words that in list2.txt

Comment: egrep -v -f file2 file1 Where file2 are the things you want removed from file1

Comment: @EssexBoy Why don't you post this as an answer? It Works.

Comment: `grep -Fxvf list2.txt list1.txt` would be better option.. will ensure that for ex: `fr` in list2.txt won't match `free` in list1.txt... `-F` since we don't need regex here, `-x` to match only whole line

Comment: if order is not important, `comm -23 <(sort list1.txt) <(sort list2.txt)`

Comment: possible duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28158/200853

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this too,

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE1=$1 # path to your list2.txt
FILE2=$2 # path to your list1.txt
touch ./tmpfile
FILE3=./tmpfile
while read p; do
  if [ `grep "\<$p\>" $FILE2 | wc -l` -ne 0 ] 
  then
    echo "$p word found discarding"
  else
    echo -e "$p" >> $FILE3
  fi
done <$FILE1
mv $FILE3 $FILE2
```

Comment: Probably the slowest approach conceivable, or pretty close to it.

Comment: yeah you are right the computational complexity goes to O(N^2). but this works as well.

Comment: @Fahad Too much unnecessary code. Can be done with a single line - one single grep as advised in OP comments.

Comment: happy learning!