# How to do anti-join or inverse join in bash

Tags: text-processing, join

I want to perform what some data analysis software call an anti-join: remove from one list those lines matching lines in another list. Here is some toy data and the expected output:

```
$ echo -e "a\nb\nc\nd" > list1
$ echo -e "c\nd\ne\nf" > list2
$ antijoincommand list1 list2
a
b
```

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/11343/117549

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a tool to get the lines in one file that are not in another?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28158/is-there-a-tool-to-get-the-lines-in-one-file-that-are-not-in-another)

Comment: @Muru, yes, that post provides the solutions presented in Terdon's answer. However, when I was searching for "bash anti-join" (the terminology I associate with this kind of process), I didn't find anything useful. My OP (which others have edited) stated that my explicit purpose in asking this question was to associate the term "anti-join" with the solutions, so that searching this term yields these solutions. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't use `join` for this because `join` requires input to be sorted, which is an unnecessary complication for such a simple job. You could instead use `grep`:

```
$ grep -vxFf list2 list1
a
b
```

Or `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{++a[$0]} !a[$0]' list2 list1
a
b
```

If the files are already sorted, an alternative to `join -v 1` would be `comm -23`

```
$ comm -23 list1 list2 
a
b
```

Comment: Avoiding `sort` with `grep` is great for the toy data I provided. Thanks! In the real world, my file1 often has multiple columns of data, one of which is being used for the join. A modified version of your `awk` code would address this use case.

Comment: @Josh yes, just change the `$0` with `$N` where `N` is the field number you are joining on.

Comment: This works even if the column numbers in file1 and file2 are different: like awk 'NR==FNR{++a[$2]} !a[$5]' list2 list1; quite usual for the tag file to be a different format to the main data.

Comment: upvoted for the `comm -23` command

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this with the `join` utility is:

```
$ join -v 1 list1 list2
a
b
```

From the manpage:

> **-a** FILENUM
>
> :   also print unpairable lines from file FILENUM, where FILENUM is 1
> or 2, corresponding to FILE1 or FILE2

> **-v** FILENUM
>
> :   like **-a** FILENUM, but suppress joined output lines

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

Raku has `Set` object types, and you can read individual files to create Sets from lines:

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $a = Set.new: "list1".IO.lines; 
            my $b = Set.new: "list2".IO.lines; 
            say "list1 = ", $a;
            say "list2 = ", $b;'
list1 = Set(a b c d)
list2 = Set(c d e f)
```

You can perform asymmetric Set differences, with either ASCII infix `(-)`, or Unicode infix `∖` :

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $a = Set.new: "list1".IO.lines; 
            my $b = Set.new: "list2".IO.lines; 
            say $a (-) $b;'
Set(a b)
```

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $a = Set.new: "list1".IO.lines; 
            my $b = Set.new: "list2".IO.lines; 
            say $b (-) $a;'
Set(e f)
```

OTOH, sometimes you need to perform a ***symmetric*** Set difference, and Raku has you covered. Use either  ASCII infix `(^)` or Unicode infix `⊖` :

```perl
~$ raku -e 'my $a = Set.new: "list1".IO.lines; 
            my $b = Set.new: "list2".IO.lines; 
            say $a (^) $b;'
Set(a b e f)
```

Finally, you can get linewise output by changing the final line to `.keys.put for` … .
Final ***symmetric*** Set difference example below, using Unicode infix `⊖` operator:

```
~$ raku -e 'my $a = Set.new: "list1".IO.lines;
            my $b = Set.new: "list2".IO.lines;
            .keys.put for $a ⊖ $b;'
f
e
a
b
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Set
https://docs.raku.org/language/setbagmix#Operators_with_set_semantics
https://raku.org